# why are the probabilities so high in this probability mass function table

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was trying to replicate [this exercise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IicA_BCFG9I&ab_channel=SamerHijazi) to generate a Normal Distribution Curve using Excel.

```
    x                    y
0.014452026         2.041422596
0.025093415         2.773027064
0.036616595         3.690210953
0.048419685         4.70609312
0.063687414         5.983995012
0.065477198         6.121209906
0.065497115         6.122714773
0.067684709         6.284810609
0.085710482         7.300373495
0.098747318         7.564268139
0.101472876         7.56198632
0.124308524         6.791278772
0.127989314         6.558494815
0.133802085         6.145728814
0.16080235          3.87480258
0.161364785         3.827066422
0.165609825         3.47247356
0.171043079         3.03728475
0.178465274         2.486521044
```

Column `x` is a column of random numbers generated using Excel's `Rand()` function

The `mean` of Column `x` is `0.099802319` and the `standard deviation` is: `0.052729812`

Column `y` is generated using Excel's `Norm.Dist()` function, with the last argument set to "False" (the `probability mass function` option)

I was able to generate a nice Normal Distribution Chart.

[image]

---

**My question for you:** Why are the values in Column `y` so large? I thought these were going to be probabilities and expected them to be `<1`.

Comment: The normal distribution is continuous and a *density*.

Comment: I bet those numbers are probability densities rather than probabilities.

Comment: @littleO I'm guessing you are right. I have to read up on probability densities, and what exactly they are.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Alex R.'s point: You're assuming that the normal distribution represents the probability of a given point $x$. But the probability of obtaining any particular real number is zero. Rather, probabilities are obtained from the normal distribution by looking at the area under the curve. For instance, the area from 0.05 to 0.15 is roughly $0.1\times 7=0.7$. So this normal distribution will produce a result between 0.05 and 0.15 about 70% of the time, which is a perfectly sensible result. (A more precise computation, taking the average as $\mu=0.1$ and the standard deviation as $\sigma=0.05$, gives a probability of about 68%. This is a characteristic result of normal distributions: About 68% of the samples are within one standard deviation of the mean.)